# how can i set the badge in tab bar in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to put the notification in the tab bar of the app to show the number of item selected for the shopping list. 
Is there any way to add the notification in the tab bar of app.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You mean the badge?  Do something like (where `self` is a `UIViewController`):

```
[[self tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:@"42"];
```

Answer (score 4):

On the storyboard you have to select your navigation view controller if you have and then open your Property window and set Badge according to your requirement.

if you want to set programmatically

```
1. find your tabbar Item by viewcontroller

 # badge=what you want to set.
```

2.[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:badge];

and if you want to set by storyboard please refer this image.

[image]

Hope this will helps.
Thanks

---

**Also if you want to use in swift. Below code will work for you**

**[[self tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:@"42"];**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the badgeValue property on a UITabBarItem to present the user with a small red badge on that item.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"2";
```